# How to pass a parameter to a Joomla 4 Wrapper component target

Tags: joomla

I'd like to pass a parameter (specifically the current username) to the external page called by an Iframe Wrapper menu item.
Any idea how I'd go about this in J4?

Don't mind if it's a GET or POST approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to create a template override for the wrapper default view, and add the user there.

So in the administrator

1. go to **system/site templates**,
2. click on your template (i.e. Cassiopeia details and files)
3. in the tab selection choose "Create Overrides" tab
4. In the second group (components) click com_wrapper then when it slides out on **wrapper**, which is the default view of the wrapper component.

now you have created a copy of the wrapper view which will not be overwritten during an update. You should already be back in the Editor tab of the Details and files. In the top of the page you should see the info message:

** info
Override created in /templates/cassiopeia/html/com_wrapper/wrapper **

Now you can either use your editor to modify it, or select **html/com_wrapper/wrapper/default.php** it in the left column to open an inline editor.

On line 34 you'll see the iframe **src** attribute:

```
 src="<?php echo $this->escape($this->wrapper->url); ?>"
```

you want to change it to include the username: i.e.

```
 src="<?php 
// step 1, get the username:
$user = Factory::getUser();
$username='guest'; // a default for non-logged in users
if (!empty($user->id)) {
  $username = $user->username;
} 

// step 2, add it to the url:
$url = $this->wrapper->url;
if (strpos($url,'?') !== false) {
  $url .= '?'
} else {
  $url .= '&'
}

$url .= 'username=' . $username;

echo $this->escape($url); ?>"
```

Comment: Does Factory::getUser(); still work in J4? I may be wrong but I thought it was deprecated??

Comment: absolutely, it's deprecated, but still working. You would be better off using a more modern approach, I didn't have the time to test it so I stuck with it, please add a comment when you get working code so I can improve my answer.